# Grab specified image source and add it into input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am trying to make the following:
On click of each image (thumbnail) source should be writen into specified input.
I have done that sort of... Not working quite fine just yet!

- It doesn't add correct source, just first source all the time, no matter what image is clicked.
- It doesn't remove added source if clicked again on same/different image.

> // Piece of jQuery script:

```
var imgSource = $('#textures li').find('img').attr('src');

$('ul#textures li img').on('click', function() {
    $('input#imgPath').val($('input#imgPath').val() + imgSource);
});​
```

Fiddle for better understanding:
[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2huF2/)

P.S. Explanation of your answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr` only returns a attribute of the first matched element, you can use `this` keyword which refers to the clicked element.

```
$('ul#textures li img').on('click', function() {
    $('#imgPath').val(this.src)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6rc/

Comment: I am trying to figure how to use .remove() if same or new image is clicked, to remove old link/path... Your sample works but stacks all sources one by one.

Comment: @NenaddvL `remove` removes the element not characters. you can use `replace` function.

Comment: One answer fully worked , but I am still trying to understand.
However, the link you provided with replace function still stacks :(

Comment: @NenaddvL I thought that you want to keep the previous value, check the updated fiddle.

Comment: Now that is easy to understand :D wohooo!
Thanks undefined fella!

Answer (score 1):

use: $(this) - that mean the attribute of the click element

```
 $('ul#textures li img').on('click', function() {
    $('input#imgPath').val($('input#imgPath').val() + $(this).attr('src'));
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/e3HzQ/

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element
>   in the matched set.

Your `imgSource` variable is declared outside of the event handler, so it doesn't vary its value according to the clicked image - it just maintains the value from the first image.

Also, the previous value isn't removed because you are appending the value to what is already there.

Comment: This works just great... It does remove the old value and it does add specified path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$('ul#textures li img').on('click', function() {
    var imgSource = $('#textures li').find('img').attr('src');
    $('input#imgPath').val($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/2huF2/7/)**

The reason it was not working for you is because you have defined

```
var imgSource = $('#textures li').find('img').attr('src');
```

outside of on function. And then further you were everytime setting the same value inside the text box using:

```
$('input#imgPath').val($('input#imgPath').val() + imgSource);
```

I modified this line to get the img src by using this operator.